# Angular2 fire fails Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have installed angular2 fire

```
 "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.0",
```

Now in my app module(root module)

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "mykey",
  authDomain: "....",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
};

imports:[
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), 
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
 ]
```

Now am geting an error

```
 Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'.
  Property 'firestore' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.


node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts (12,28):
  Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
```

Where am i going wrong or what else do i need to add to have it work

Comment: `firebase.Promise` was removed in Firebase 4.5.0. AngularFire 5.0 accounts for this change. You're likely still on the old AngularFire package.

Comment: ive added the package.json angular2 fire value which shows its 5.0

Comment: Instead of `rc.0`, try `rc.2`

Comment: @fshock now it works, thanks.

Comment: That's great @GEOFFREY. May I add that comment as answer then?

Comment: yes add as an anser ill surely mark it then, to help another person with similar issue

Comment: Property 'firestore' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'. 

How did you fixed this error ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase.Promise` was removed in Firebase 4.5.0.  `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2"` accounts for this change. This version should solve the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install anularfire2 --save` command it should work

Comment: One liners are not good answers. Although it may solve the problem it doesn't attempt to explain it or mention why the command works. Not even what it does.